# Hiding window decorations when maximized on Gnome3

Tags: gnome

On 10.04, I had had a very handy option from Compiz that allowed me to hide the window decorations (including the titlebar) when window was maximized.

How do I achieve the same with GNOME 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(the questions is a bit old, but might be useful for someone)

Webupd8, has some really nice tutorials on customization regarding gnome shell.

This is for removing the window decoration when maximized: 
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-remove-maximized-windows.html

And this explains how to add Unity-like buttons (maximize, minimize, close) to the top-bar.
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/get-unity-like-window-buttons-on-top.html

They worked for me, and I have noticed no bugs or crashes.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117936